# how to loop in xml (XElement) and get values od Inside Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Consider this XML:

[image]

I store  this `XML` in `XElemnt`.How I can loop throw `Person` elements and get value `ID,Name,LastName`  for each person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `XElement`, you will get all the people in `people` variable.

```
XElement d = XElement.Load("D:\\people.xml");
var people = (from p in d.Descendants("Person")
                select new
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("ID").Value),
                    Name = p.Element("Name").Value,
                    LastName = p.Element("LastName").Value
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(<filePath>);
var people = from person in doc.Descendents("Person")
select new Person{
    ID = (int)person.Element("ID"),
    Name = (string)person.Element("Name"),
    LastName = (string)person.Element("LastName");
};

return people.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm using XElement.please say how to use XElement with your sample

Comment: you could replace doc with your XElement, I suppose. XElement has a Load method as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435.aspx